# Ignore super class field in derived class

Tags: java, json

I have an abstract super class with the field "UserId" and a derived class that uses all the parent's classes but "UserId". will @JsonIgnore on a similarly named Derived field prevent the serialization of the superclass's "UserId"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: I am about to, just wanted tlo have this ready in case it doesn't work :-)

Comment: @JBNizet: testing is fine, but it can only answer the question 'will it work in this particular case', not 'should it work because it is the intended way'. Sometimes you can start depending on undocumented behavior or a bug.